# Nagios email alert configuration

Tags: email, ubuntu-16.04, nagios, postfix-mta

I am configuring Nagios to send email alerts through postfix configured to an SMTP Relay Server, I have configured my commands.cfg and contacts.cfg to contain the required settings. However, whenever the email goes out, it is not picking up the configurations I have in my contacts.cfg and always takes a default email id:

```
Mar 26 02:20:05 dash postfix/pickup[24908]: 395DBBE0DC3: uid=1002 from=<oem>
Mar 26 02:20:05 dash postfix/cleanup[25635]: 395DBBE0DC3: message-id=<20180325205005.395DBBE0DC3@dash.in>
Mar 26 02:20:05 dash postfix/qmgr[17430]: 395DBBE0DC3: from=<oem@dash.in>, size=595, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 26 02:20:10 dash postfix/smtp[25637]: 395DBBE0DC3: to=<oem@dash.in>, orig_to=<oem>, relay=relay.smtp.dash.in:587, delay=5.6, delays=0.01/0.01/3.8/1.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 010101625eecf59b-243d9f21-ae1c-4272-9213-55e11d7d5e25-000000)
Mar 26 02:20:11 dash postfix/qmgr[17430]: 395DBBE0DC3: removed
```

I have not configured the oem user anywhere in postfix or nagios, however there is an oem user on my system. I'm missing something basic I feel, if anyone has any idea do let me know.
Cheers!

Comment: Is nagios running as the OEM user?  Postfix is receiving the mail from the unix system locally, it's why the first process in the mail is the pickup process. If it was coming through the TCP stack the first process would be smtp.

Comment: @Stephan yes you are right I figured out that this was coming from the unix system locally. Is there a way I can disable system emails on Nagios, 'coz I do not need this email.

Comment: This is a nagios question I'm unsure about.  Contact support?

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to find out where it is configured:

```
$ sudo grep -s -R "oem@dash.in" /etc/*
$ sudo grep -s -R "oem@dash.in" /usr/local/nagios/*

$ cat /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg | grep @
admin_email=myaccount@gmail.com
admin_pager=myaccount@gmail.com

$ cat /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg | grep @
    email                   nagios@localhost ; <<***** CHANGE THIS TO YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS ******
    email                   myaccount@gmail.com;
```

Test your configuration by:

```
$ echo "Test Email message body" | mail -r account_accepted_by_relay@mydomainname.onmicrosoft.com -s "Email test subject" myaccount@gmail.com
```

I've installed mailutils before using that test command:

```
$ sudo apt install mailutils
```

I'm using sendgrid, so my **main.cf** configuration includes:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost.localdomain

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

You could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021433/10854998) for more detailed explanation.